# Converting an enum to a member variable [PROBLEM] C++

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I am trying to create a lookup for variables of different types corresponding to different enum values  within a struct.

Here is the solution I have so far:

```
struct X {
    int x;
    std::string y;
    char z;
    enum class MYENUM {
        X, Y, Z
    };
    template<MYENUM TYPE>
    auto& GetAttribute() {
        if constexpr (TYPE == MYENUM::X) return x;
        else if constexpr (TYPE == MYENUM::Y) return y;
        else if constexpr (TYPE == MYENUM::Z) return z;
    }
};
```

I am in search for a more elegant solution, as in my actual project, I have many different variables within my struct, and thus the if/else block becomes very large.

Comment: The function doesn't seem to have anything upon which it can infer the template arguments.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
template<MYENUM TYPE>
auto& GetAttribute() {
    return std::get<int(TYPE)>(std::tie(x, y, z));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zETYo5)

(You are essentially reinventing `std::tuple`.)

Comment: Basically you `tie` the three variables in a `tuple` and then accede to them through the `enum`. Wow, clever and *pythonesque*..